# Website to generate Ethereum Hash of a PDF file

Tags: dapp-development, dapps

I would like to ask a user to generate a "Keccak-256" or "Keccak-512" (Ethereum versions of SHA3) of a PDF file. Is there a recommended website with a good GUI to generate that?

The user would input a PDF file and the system will return "Keccak-256" or "Keccak-512" of this file.

Obs.: I know I can program a service to that. It is just a MVP.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [this website](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256_checksum.html) to create a Keccak256 or Keccack512 checksum of a file:

[image]

Source code can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/emn178/online-tools).